# Solve this definite integral

Tags: calculus

I have a problem with this definite integral. Please help me:

$$ f(x)= {\int }\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}} dx $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $w=e^{2x}$, then $dw=2e^{2x}dx$, and
$$\int \frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}dx=\int\frac{1+e^{2x}-e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}dx=\int dx -\int \frac{e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}dx =x-\int \frac{\frac{dw}{2}}{1+w}=$$
$$=x-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dw}{w+1}=x-\frac{1}{2}\ln|w+1|+c=x-\frac{1}{2}\ln (1+e^{2x})+c. $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use the substitution $u=e^{2x} $ then use partial fraction.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$I=\int\frac1{1+e^{2x}}dx=\int\frac{e^{-x}dx}{e^{-x}+e^{x}}$$

Setting $\displaystyle e^{-x}=v,I=-\int\frac{vdv}{1+v^2}$

Set $1+v^2=u$

Comment: Even easier: $\int \frac{e^{-2x} \, dx}{e^{-2x}+1}$ followed by $u=e^{-2x}+1$.